# Is TryGetValue on ConcurrentDictionary atomic?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

Can I call TryGetValue on ConcurrentDictionary and safely assume that the value is not changed in the course of operation. Also, what happens when another thread tries to Add with same key when this operation is happening? Some pseudo code to explain question. I know this is less than ideal example. But, when TryAdd is in progress with key k1, will TryGetValue with same key k1 wait for TryAdd to finish? Similarly, if TryGetValue for key k1 is in progress, will TryAdd for same key k1 wait for TryGetVaule to finish?

```
class Test
{ 
   ConcurrentDictionary<string, Data> cache;

   public void CalculateAndAddToCache(string key)
   {
        Data val; 
        if (cache.TryGetValue(key, out val))
        {
             return;
        }
        val = // some large computation
        cache.TryAdd(key, val); 
   }
}
```

Comment: There is not enough context in your question to provide a good answer. There are far too many different possibilities, and what happens and whether that's a problem depends a lot on the code that's using the dictionary object.

Comment: @PeterDuniho..I'm trying to understand if TryAdd method is blocked for TryGetValue or not (assuming same keys are used) and vice-versa.

Comment: I guess that depends on your definition of "blocked". But in general, I'd so "no, not necessarily". That is, you cannot be sure that if one thread has called `TryGetValue()`, that no other thread can observe a call to `TryAdd()` complete. It would depend on the order of synchronization in the dictionary object, which could randomly wind up allowing the add to complete first. Of course, in that case, when the `TryGetValue()` _did_ complete, it'd see the added key. The object will remain coherent. But you can't be sure which will happen first, if they are both initiated concurrently.

Comment: @PeterDuniho.. I think I got the point. Please correct me if I'm wrong. If TryAdd and TryGetValue are called in parellel, the second one to complete will respect the state of the object as modified by the first one to complete. We can never guarantee the relative ordering though.

Comment: Correct. Noting of course that `TryGetValue()` does not actually modify the object. :) But yes...assuming just two concurrently executing threads, if `TryGetValue()` completes first in one thread and returns `false`, `TryAdd()` in another thread will succeed. Conversely, if `TryAdd()` completes first in one thread, `TryGetValue()` will in the other thread succeed and return `true`.

Comment: Use the `GetOrAdd` method.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is "yes", but it doesn't help you because the value could change as soon as TryGetValue exists and before you've had a chance to read the result.

If another thread tries to Add, nothing bad happens. That thread might block while TryGetValue completes, or it might complete concurrently - it depends on implementation details of the ConcurrentDictionary, its ConcurrencyLevel and the hashcode of the keys in question.

Comment: _"If another thread tries to Add, nothing bad happens"_ -- I guess that depends on whether the dictionary already had that key, as well as one's definition of "bad". Adding a key that already exists will throw an exception. And even if the key doesn't already exist, if it's "bad" for the thread querying the dictionary to think it doesn't exist when in fact it now does, then something "bad" could in fact happen.

Comment: That's why there is no plain "Add" method on ConcurrentDictionary. There's "TryAdd" or "AddOrUpdate", but nothing that's subject to races.

Comment: There is an `Add()` method, it's just exposed as an explicit implementation of [`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287241(v=vs.110).aspx).